# fiter fields from api laravel request

Tags: php, laravel, api, filter, backend

> *https://public.tes/api/sales-invoice/list.do?fields=id%2Cno%2Cname*

when making requests to api development, you can also request any fields that appear such as name, address or so on.is there any reference for this?

Answer (score 0):

**Example 1**

```
// Query string
?fields=id%2Cno%2Cname

// Backend - PHP - Laravel
$request->input('fields'); // "id, no, name"
```

**Example 2**

```
// Query string
?fields[]=id&fields[]=no&fields[]=name

// Backend - PHP - Laravel
$request->input('fields'); // [ 'id', 'no', 'name' ]
```